# Spring/hibernate configuration error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, glassfish

I'm new at Java Spring and Hibernate and I'm trying to build an application with those technologies (Maven, Spring and Hibernate). When I try to run it I receive an error from the glassfish server, It's a very long stacktrace, but this is the last part:

```
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:
ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: CentricJavaDB not found
```

I'm trying things out for hours but I don't find my mistake. I'm pretty sure it's in a configuration xml file but I can't fix it. I hope some of u guys can help me (:

The configuration files:

Dispatcher servlet in the WEB-INF folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="service"/>
    <bean name = "klantDao" class="service.JpaKlantDao"/>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/CentricJavaDB"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>domain</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" /> 
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
             </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" 
          class=" org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager ">
        <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />
</beans>
```

glassfish-web.xml in WEB-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
 <Resource name="jdbc/CentricJavaDB" auth="Container"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username="root"
    password="root"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/centricjavadb" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

I also found this file "Other Sources\Setup\glassfish-resources.xml". I don't see big differences with "glassfish-web.xml" but it also contains database information. I think it also could be important:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" 
                          associate-with-thread="false" 
                          connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" 
                          connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10"
                          connection-leak-reclaim="false" 
                          connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" 
                          connection-validation-method="auto-commit" 
                          datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" 
                          fail-all-connections="false" 
                          idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" 
                          is-connection-validation-required="false" 
                          is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" 
                          lazy-connection-association="false" 
                          lazy-connection-enlistment="false" 
                          match-connections="false" 
                          max-connection-usage-count="0" 
                          max-pool-size="32" 
                          max-wait-time-in-millis="60000"
                          name="jdbc/CentricJavaDB" 
                          non-transactional-connections="false" 
                          pool-resize-quantity="2" 
                          res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
                          statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" 
                          steady-pool-size="8" 
                          validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" 
                          jndi-name="jdbc/CentricJavaDB"
                          wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="centricjavadb"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value="root"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/centricjavadb"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool> 
</resources>
```

I think the error is caused because of the jndi-lookup can't find the datasource in glassfish-web.xml, but correct me if I'm wrong.

I think this should be enough information. If you want more files, stacktraces or whatever, just ask and I will post it.

Answer (score 1):

JNDI resources are often tricky to figure out.

Stacktrace points to a  problem with how you data source is defined. According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-4335/ablij/index.html) :

> *Expect to find the JNDI name of a JDBC resource in java:comp/env/jdbc*

Trying putting the following in your config:

```
 <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/CentricJavaDB"/>
```

Though according to this question: [Spring 3 JNDI look up in glassfish3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911624/spring-3-jndi-look-up-in-glassfish3) this is not necessary

Comment: Thx but now I receive this error:
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:comp/env/jdbc/CentricJavaDB

Comment: Hmm... Sorry, i am not familiar with glassfish. You mentioned that you defined datasource in glassfish-web.xml. Should not it be defined on a server?

Comment: Haha I'm not familiar with glassfish too. But I don't know, I thought glassfish can find the configuration files by name, but I'm not sure.
I also found another file that could be important, I wil add it to my question. Thanks anyway!